# Solr setting physical memory less than index size and out of memory

Tags: solr

Is there a setting in Solr 4.3.1 where say my Memory is 15G and my index size is 75G. I always get an out of memory exception . I am updating the indexes in chunks of 50000 and when my index size reached 14.8G , I get an out of memory exception. I turned off all the caching in solrconfig.xml.

Anyway I can push all of them all to index or is it impossible in solr, I also allocated 4 G to JVM which seems to be fine.

Let me know if there are any options

Comment: How often are you committing? (Or do you have auto commit configured in solrconfig?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, solr 4.3 will mmap index into memory, you may try other DirectoryFactory, such as  SimpleFSDirectoryFactory.

See DirectoryFactory section in solrconfig.xml.

Comment: Thanks , am looking into this , my guess is , this might work . Will update soon.